# Text object gets deleted in Adobe Reader 11

Tags: adobe-reader

In Adobe Acrobat X I was inserting text objects. It opens properly in Adobe Reader 10, but in Adobe Reader 11, when I click on that PDF file, text objects get deleted.

Why does this happen? How can I solve it?
here is the source pdf file which i am editing [click here](http://incometaxsoft.com/pdf/Src.pdf)

This the pdf file which is already edited and text gets deleted when double click on pdf in adobe reader 11 [click here](http://incometaxsoft.com/pdf/result.pdf)

Comment: I'm guessing they're simply not being displayed in Reader 11 for whatever reason. I doubt it is actually editing the PDF and deleting the objects from it.

Comment: So how can i retain those text objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is setup for input using the Typewriter Tool, which displays when the file is opened.
When you select this tool, the input/typing area has a blue border, so you can click on the border handles to resize the input area or move it where you need it.

NOTE: If you do not type and add data in the input area, it goes away. It will not redisplay until you select the Typewriter Tool again.

Ideally, form fields should have been added in Acrobat X, and then enabled for Reader. At that point, you could enter data by simply tabbing between fields.